# VBA If For statement- Next

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set up this macro so it will skip to my next `indx` if a cell equals "Not Completed". The problem I am having is that I have to use a different variable and it will just run the `For` statement and end the macro.

Do I need a `For` statement? If I put `Next Indx` after it marks the cell "Not Completed" it will error out.

This what I have set up at the beginning of the macro:

```
  Dim indx As Integer
  For indx = 4 To 1000
  ordnbr = Sheet1.Cells(indx, 1)
  If Trim(ordnbr) = "" Then
        Exit For
  End If
```

Before the code below I have my if statements...

```
    Else: Sheet1.Cells(indx, 9) = "Not Competed"
    End If

    For indx = 4 To 6
    If Trim(Status) = "Not Completed" Then
    Next indx
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you want this:

```
For indx = 4 To 6
    If Trim(Status) = "Not Completed" Then
        'do nothing, which ultimately causes indx to skip to next in sequence
    Else
        'put some code here to do something, next in sequence will occur naturally
    End If
Next indx
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the loops are misaligned here.

If Else Endif should be all within the For loop. I revised it a little bit, as follows:

```
    Sub subname()

     Dim indx As Integer

     a = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        For indx = 4 To a
        ordnbr = Sheet1.Cells(indx, 1)
        If Trim(ordnbr) = "" Then
        Else: Sheet1.Cells(indx, 9) = "Not Competed"
        End If
        Next

    End Sub
```